# How can I enable Groovy plugin features in my eclipse plugin?

Tags: groovy, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an eclipse plugin which needs to support features from the Groovy eclipse plugin.

The Groovy website talks about Groovy eclipse plugins, and Groovy compiler support within eclipse and maven, but I did not find anything similar to what I need to do here.

If I look at the list of available plugin dependencies, I see a number of them:

[image]

1. How can I enable some discovery mechanism or otherwise, in order to install the Groovy plugin after the installation of my plugin completes?
2. Which plugin can I add as dependency to achieve this? Or should I have to individually add all of them?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add single plug-ins you can easily do that in the Manifest-Editor of your plug-in. If you need to add a dependency to a feature, you need to create a feature for your own plug-in and add the additional feature dependency in the feature-Editor.

To find out which groovy plug-ins are required to add the "groovy compiler support", I suppose you must rather look at the groovy features in your installation. Usually complex features like a compiler or the like are grouped within a feature.

Add on:

1. I think the discovery mechanism is already integrated in p2.
2. I suppose these plug-ins are part of a feature. Find this feature and add that to your product.

For stability I would recommend to add the specific plug-ins to your product/feature. That way you can be sure, people are using the exact version you proposed in your implmentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think the problem is just not to enable plugins, but that can only happen when the installation has the groovy plugins available. Please check my update.